# Render image in custom webpart from Picture Library

Tags: sharepoint

I have a custom webpart that is displaying dynamic list data, it needs to render an image from a Picture Library (or at least provide me the URL so I can encapsulate it with an  tag), however, none of the fields in the Picture Library seem to contain the image URL?  Is there a 'image utility' (SPImageUtility) or something I can use to pull this out?  Or am I simply missing something?

Answer (score 2):

Assuming you are using the object model then the you should use this (c#)

```
SPListItem["EncodedAbsUrl"]
```

to get the HTML encoded absolute URL of the image (where "**EncodedAbsUrl**" is the name of the field/column).

To get the unencoded site relative url you can use **ServerUrl** or **FileRef** (they appear to return the same)

You can also use **EncodedAbsThumbnailUrl** to get a thumbnail image.

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/microsoft.sharepoint.splistitem.aspx

Answer (score 0):

Are getting information from a CAML query? If so you will need to add the required field to the query.

Otherwise the spListItem object from the spList has the property URL which has a web relative URL for the image.